# Ajax Form Returns Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post a form through AJAX in Netsuite so that I could trigger an event after the form submit without actually reloading it.

Please help me out, I am a newbie with AJAX.

Here is the code

```
$('#du_joinnow').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
  var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
  $.ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://forms.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl?compid=XXXXXX&formid=1&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"+ formdata,
    data: formdata,
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#overlay').fadeIn(); //data: return data from server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Ajax Call Failed.");//if fails
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I havent added any eventlisteners, it just says Ajax Call Failed. How do I add Error Listeners here?

Comment: I guess the url should remove parameter, if you use url with parameter, you should use `GET` method not `POST`.

Comment: You can try remove `formdata` after url string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$.ajaxSubmit` do `$.ajax`

Full Code:

```
$('#du_joinnow').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://forms.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl?compid=XXXXXX&formid=1&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + formdata,
        data: formdata,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(); //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Ajax Call Failed."); //if fails
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have tried many things like using $.ajax , using serialize() instead of serializeArray(). But no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#du_joinnow').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
  var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();
   $.ajax({
                url:"https://forms.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalleadpage.nl?compid=XXXXXX&formid=1&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + formdata,
                type:"POST",
                data: formdata,
                    complete:function(data) {
                        if (data.readyState == 4)
                          {
                            if (data.status == 200)
                            {
                              $('#overlay').fadeIn(); 
                              alert(data.responseText);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              alert("Ajax Call Failed.");
                              alert(data.statusText);
                            }
                          }
                    }

                });
  return false;
});
```